# ListView.getItemAtPosition always return 0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

I am creating a contact application that works with SQLite database and I face a problem when I try to pass the id of the contact to another intent to use it in a query.
Here is my code :
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView contactsList;
    DbContact dbContact;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactsList = findViewById(R.id.contactList);
        dbContact = new DbContact(this);

        contactsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, update_contact.class);

                Contact selected_contact =(Contact) contactsList.getItemAtPosition(i);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ths position is " +selected_contact.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*intent.putExtra("id", selected_contact.getId());
                startActivity(intent);*/
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**update_contact.java:**

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_contact);

        int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0);
        db = new DbContact(this);
        editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
        editPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
        btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

        Contact contact = db.getContactById(id);
        editName.setText(contact.getName());
        editPhone.setText(contact.getPhone());
    }
```

**BdContact :**

```
 public DbContact(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String create_table = "create table "+TABLE_CONTACTS+"("+KEY_ID+" int primary key AUTOINCREMENT, "+KEY_NAME+" varchar(30), "+KEY_PHONE+" varchar(30))";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(create_table);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        String delete_table = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_CONTACTS;
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(delete_table);

        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public void addContact(Contact contact){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE, contact.getPhone());

        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    }

    public ArrayList<Contact> getAllContacts(){
        ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

        String selectAll_query = "select * from "+ TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectAll_query, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_NAME));
                String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_PHONE));

                Contact contact = new Contact(id,name, phone);

                contacts.add(contact);

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return contacts;
    }

    public Contact getContactById(int id_contact){
        Contact contact = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String select_query = "select * from "+TABLE_CONTACTS+" where id = " + id_contact;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(select_query, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_NAME));
            String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_PHONE));
            contact = new Contact(id, name, phone);
        }

        return contact;
    }
```

*I think that the problem is in the database because I suspect the id didn't auto-incremented*
Thank you guys for helping me solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the position?

> listView.getItemAtPosition(position)

Comment: Yes my friend here it is :
Contact selected_contact =(Contact) contactsList.getItemAtPosition(i);
The variable i refer to the position of the clicked item in onItemClick()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).